# Vim Find Wildcard Value and Replace With same wildcard with small pertibation

Tags: text, vim, replace, edit

I wish to find an occurrence of a specific symbol inside a large string and prepend a space to that symbol.

NOTE: I also have occurrences in the file with the space already prepended to that symbol.

input

```
6890 4 2.025 12.219883 -80.86158
6891 1 36.45 11.314275-79.050365
6892 1 36.45 14.031098-79.955972
6893 1 2.025 13.12549-78.144757
```

output:

```
6890 4 2.025 12.219883 -80.86158
6891 1 36.45 11.314275 -79.050365
6892 1 36.45 14.031098 -79.955972
6893 1 2.025 13.12549 -78.144757
```

I first thought that the solution would have the following form

```
:%s/*-*/* -*/
```

This form does not account for the existing spaces

Comment: Vim uses regular expressions. See `:help pattern` for the full doc and [http://vimregex.com/](http://vimregex.com/) for a quick overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:%s/\(\d\)-/\1 -/g
```

in entire file `%` substitute `s/` a digit `\d`, (and capture it `\(\d\)`) followed by a minus `-`, and replace `/` with what was captured `\1` followed by space and minus  `-` with options `/` "all occurrences on the line" `g`